# Accompanied child has a visa with my old passport number in it

Tags: visas

I will go to the UK next week with one of my students. In her visa, my old passport number is written. After she got her visa, I changed my passport and the number has changed. Do you think it will be a problem if I provide my old passport too?

Comment: It’s fine. Carry both of your passports

Answer (score 2):

No problem, provided you still have your old passport and carry it with you.